# Obtener un valor de una consulta find Mongoose Schemas

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

mi duda es la siguiente, tengo esta funcion

```
async function AutoIncremental() {
    try {
        let query = { variable: "tid" }
        var sort=[];
        var operador={$inc: {secuencia: 1} };
        var options= {new:true};
        let res = await Usuario.find(query);
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
}
```

la cual llamo en esta ruta

```
app.get("/secuencia", async (req,res)=>{
    let resultado = await AutoIncremental();
    console.log(resultado);
    })
```

al momento de ejecutar en postman me devuelve esta informacion

```
El servidor de PetRescue está corriendo por el servidor : 8080
[
  {
    ultimoLogin: 2020-08-07T18:52:22.366Z,    
    creacionUsuario: 2020-08-07T18:52:22.366Z,
    _id: 5f2caa3d1d7b01381254bc1b,
    variable: 'tid',
    secuencia: 2
  }
]
```

Como puedo hacer para obtener el valor de "secuencia" y almacenarlo en una variable, lo he intentado en la funcion async colocando de esta forma

- return res.value.secuencia
- return res.secuencia
- return res[0].secuencia

pero en todas estas me devuelve undefinied

si alguien pudiera aconsejarme como hacerlo

Comment: Tienes que acceder a la variable `resultado` que es la que tiene el resultado de la query. Así `resultado[0].secuencia` y no `res`.

Comment: Si lo he intentado con la variable resultado, pero de igual forma me tira undefined

Answer (score 0):

Debes de quitar el `async` y el `await` del método. Solo debes de dejarlo en la función `AutoIncremental()`

De esta manera

```
app.get("/secuencia", (req,res)=>{
    let resultado = AutoIncremental();
    console.log(resultado);

    //Termina la ejecucion de tu metodo get
    return res.send(resultado)
    })
```

Despues debes agregar en tu metodo:

```
async function AutoIncremental() {
    try {
        let query = { variable: "tid" }
        var sort=[];
        var operador={$inc: {secuencia: 1} };
        var options= {new:true};
        // Esta es la clave el exec()
        let res = await Usuario.find(query).exec()

        //Esto funciona
        console.log(res[0].secuencia)
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
}
```